# Swift: Keep segue from executing if condition not met

Tags: ios, swift, segue

Currently I'm working on two different ViewControllers in my application, we can call them VC1 and VC2. VC1 displays a registration form, with a question in each row of a UITableView, and has an edit button. The edit button is as a segue from VC1 and VC2. VC2 displays an interface that will allow the user to edit the question. I want to write the application so that you cannot segue from VC1 to VC2 unless you have selected a question(row) to edit. Right now I have some of it set up, but it's possible that I have it backwards.

In VC1:

```
// this method isn't called until VC2 segues back to VC1... so I don't know how
// to make sure that a selection has been made before pressing the button
@IBAction func editQuestion(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
        if let editQuestion = segue.sourceViewController as? VC2 {

        }
}
```

In VC2:

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject!) -> Bool {

    // check to make sure that user has completed all fields of question
    // if they haven't completed all fields, return false (do not segue)
    // else segue to VC1
}
```

Comment: The check before performing the segue should happen in VC1 before you call performSegueWithIdentifier()

Comment: Yes I understand that. I'm not really sure how to do that though. You got any ideas? The structure I have right now does not lend itself to that.

Comment: How are you calling the segue to VC2? is it hooked up in storyboard?

Comment: Yes. Both are hooked up to the StoryBoard. I ctrl-clicked the edit button in VC1 to VC2 and ctrl-clicked the save button in VC2 to the exit in VC2 which sends it to the editQuestion function in VC1. Everything is hooked up and segues properly, I just don't know how to go about checking to see if a question was selecting before pressing edit.

Comment: Question. Let's say I checked the value of the selected index for a question in the ViewDidAppear method of VC2. If the index is -1, I know nothing has been selected. Is there a way to send it back to VC1 through ViewDidAppear?

Comment: Don't quite understand you, but if you are in a navigation controller, you could pop the view from the navigation stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement in VC1:

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        if identifier == <your storyboard segue identifier> {

        }
    }
```

Give your storyboard segue an identifier, and then you can do the check in VC1, and return false if you do not want the segue to happen.

Comment: So I should have a shouldPerformSeguieWithIdentifier in both VC1 and VC2? Can you do that? I'm using an identifier in VC2.

Comment: You should have that check in VC1. You can have it in VC2, but it will only be useful after you are already segued to VC2.

Comment: I have multiple segues in VC1. Will it know which views to segue to?

Comment: Yes, that gets called for every segue if you override it, it just won't do anything if you don't have any code for that identifier.